# Implicit function theorem and PDE; do we get uniqueness?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Please see this page: [The implicit function theorem: A PDE example](http://anhngq.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/the-implicit-function-theorem-a-pde-example/).

In the implicit function theorem they quote, uniqueness is not mentioned. But the inverse function theorem (which is equivalent to the IMFT), we do get uniqueness. So am I right that the solution got by using the theorem is unique as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Their statement of the Implicit Function theorem does contain a uniqueness part: "$F(x,y)=0$ if and **only** if".
2. However, this is a local statement, only for $(x,y)\in U\times V$. It does not exclude the possibility of having other solutions outside of small neighborhood $V$.

Comment: So this gives us a local (eg. short-time for parabolic pdes) solution, am I right? Strange that none of the source I have looked at points out local uniqueness.

Comment: @hopo2 The neighborhood is taken in the function space, not in the space-time coordinates. So it's not "short-time uniqueness", it's uniqueness among the functions that are close to the particular solution.